# Accessibility - triggering hover and focus events on TAB key press

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

I've been dabbling in simple CSS transitions and hover events etc recently. I notice that when you press the TAB key it generally finds links which is fine but...

If I have a hover event, like a piece of text is revealed or something similar, how can I ensure that pressing the TAB key will trigger hover and or focus events?

This is because I have a page full of squares made up of `DIVs` that look similar to this:

[image]

When you hover over this block with your mouse it changes color via a hover event, essentially to visually inform the user that the element is in some way interactive.

Is there a way I could trigger the hover event with the TAB key or even the arrow keys? My reasoning is because if for some reason you did not have a mouse or touch device you could potentially miss out on content.

**Amending my question slightly**

So the TAB key is treated as a `:focus` event and works well when you give a link a `:hover` state but is it possible for the TAB key to acknowledge DIV elements?

Comment: `:focus` ? have you tried something ?

Comment: I was going to try and bind a keydown event on the TAB key to a focus event but I wasn't sure whether this was overkill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is with respect to your last comment:

> So the TAB key is treated as a :focus event and works well when you give a link a :hover state but is **it possible for the TAB key to acknowledge DIV elements**?

I believe you are looking for [`tabindex="0"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex).  Adding that attribute will make your element capable of receiving focus.

So `<div tabindex="0">Hello World</div>`

The `tabindex` doesn't **have** to be 0.  It can be negative, 0, or a possitive integer following these rules:

From [MDN on tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

> - a negative value means that the element should be focusable, but should not be reachable via sequential keyboard navigation;
> - 0 means that the element should be focusable and reachable via sequential keyboard navigation, but its relative order is defined by
>     the platform convention;
> - a positive value means should be focusable and reachable via sequential keyboard navigation; its relative order is defined by the
>     value of the attribute: the sequential follow the increasing number of
>     the tabindex. If several elements share the same tabindex, their
>     relative order follows their relative position in the document.

Comment: Using a positive tabindex [is almost always a bad idea](http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/tabindex). In this particular case, adding a tabindex to a non-interactive element will decrease the accessibility. It adds nothing and will likely confuse users that navigate with the keyboard.

Comment: I agree with @steveax on **not** using positive values for `tabindex`.  0 and -1 are the only values you should use.  But I disagree on using `tabindex` for non-interative elements.  Having a non-interactive element receive focus can be very beneficial and can increase accessibility.  But without talking about specific examples, it's not worth discussing at the moment.

Answer (score 10):

With CSS you can use also `:focus`, try this:

```css
div {
  float:left;
  margin:2px;
}
a {
  display:block;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  line-height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  background:purple;
  color:white;
  transition:.3s linear;
}
a:hover, a:focus {
  background:orange;
}
```

```html
<div><a href="">item1</a></div>
<div><a href="">item2</a></div>
<div><a href="">item3</a></div>
<div><a href="">item4</a></div>
<div><a href="">item5</a></div>
```